# Scalable database design for general catalog of ítems that mixes with particular catalog for each user?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scalability

I would like to have a general catalog of threats that will be used initially for all users. The catalog has approximately 100 threats. The threats has relations with other models like for example AssetType. One threat affects multiple asset_types and one asset_type is affected by multiple threats.

My problem is that I would like the users to modify the threats in the catalog, delete threats and add threats but the modification of the catalog need to be only for him, not for the rest of users. The same with asset_types and the relationships. I would like each user to be able to modify the relationships but not for all users.

The way I have though is that I can have CatalogThreat and CatalogAssetType and CatalogThreatsAssetTypes that will be the general catalog and when a new user is created I will copy each catalog_threat to a table called threats where each threat will be related to the user. But this way I think I will have a lot of duplicity because I think that users are going to modify very little the catalog.

Have you any alternatives? Is this a good database design? Any design pattern I should know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real alternative to copying everything is to model a list of changes to the main catalog.  So if a user deletes something from the catalog you would store this in a record indicating "just like the main catalog except Fred has deleted Threat 3".  If they insert a new relationship, you would need to store that.

Querying this model will be quite difficult because you will need to select catalog records where not exists a delete from the current user unioned with any inserts from the current user.  Depending on your database, you might be able to wrap this in a view.

Comment: Reading your opinion I think that it is better for me to mantain the copy procedure. The overhead of the alternate solution is not worth it having into account the quantity of data I will have. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's what will be easier. Might be hard if you change the master data and want everyone's custom version to change.